# Codeigniter ajax accessing userdata

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm populating a select box field depending on the selected option of another select box.

```
$.get(window.location + '/controller/load_options?options=' + option, function(data) {
  ...   
}
```

In my controller:

```
function load_options() {
  $this->user = $this->session->userdata('user');
  var_dump($this->user); // returns null
}
```

The `user` data is set and can be viewed in other controllers, but it seems to be reset when I try accessing it through an ajax request.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Try load_options() directly on the browser without ajax and see if you get results.

Comment: Trying it directly on the browser still yields false, but on the index page, I clearly set all the session variables. I can even print them out before I load the view. It's as if all my information gets reset when I do the ajax/second request.